# Java: failed to write on Excel file successfully

Tags: java, excel

To write to an Excel file, I have written the following code:

```
File mazeMap = new File("myFile.xlsx");
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(mazeMap);
WritableSheet wsheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
Label label=new Label(1, 1, "I am here");    
wsheet.addCell(label);
if(workbook!= null )
    workbook.write();

workbook.close();
```

By this code, I expect to have an Excel file with name `myfile.xlsx`, and in one of its workbooks there should be `"I am here"`

Although, I created the file, I could not open it because the file is corrupted.

What is wrong with the code?

I used `jx.jar`

Comment: Do you mean you're using `JExcelApi`? If so note that they state: "Generates spreadsheets in Excel 2000 format" - xlsx is not supported. Try Apache POI instead.

Comment: @Thomas yes, so what should i use for **xslx**?

Comment: he told you : apache POI ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
https://github.com/eBay/xcelite

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
            <artifactId>xcelite</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

public class User { 

  @Column (name="Firstname")
  private String firstName;

  @Column (name="Lastname")
  private String lastName;

  @Column
  private long id; 

  @Column
  private Date birthDate; 
}


Xcelite xcelite = new Xcelite();    
XceliteSheet sheet = xcelite.createSheet("users");
SheetWriter<User> writer = sheet.getBeanWriter(User.class);
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
// ...fill up users
writer.write(users); 
xcelite.write(new File("users_doc.xlsx"));
```